# MongoDB aggregation - project field values as fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Having some trouble getting my data into a tricky format.

Documents have these fields: `subject, importance [high,medium,low]`

sample document:

```
{_id: "", subject: "red", importance: "high"}
```

I like to return data that looks like:

```
[{_id: subject, high: 5, medium: 6, low: 3}]
```

The numbers correspond with the number of documents with each importance level

This is what I have so far:

```
{
$group: {
  _id: {subject: "$subject", importance: "$importance"},
  count: {$sum: 1},
  }
 },
 {
   $group: {
     _id: "$_id.subject",
     data: {
       $push: {
          importance: "$_id.importance", count: "$count"
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Is there a way that I can use the value of `$_id.importance` and make that the key and have `$count` as the value?

Comment: Can you please post a sample document?

Comment: Documents are like this {_id: "", subject: "red", importance: "high"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could aggregate as below:

- [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) by `subject` and `importance`, get the respective counts.
- Then comes the tricky part, the conditional [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/project/), it would grow linearly with respect to the number of options the `importance` field could hold. currently it is three - `high`, `low` and `medium`.
- `$group` the result back again by `subject` and use the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) operator to `accumulate` the counts for the different values of the importance field.

sample code:

```
db.t.aggregate([
{$group:{"_id":{"subject":"$subject",
                "importance":"$importance"},
         "count":{$sum:1}}},
{$project:{"_id":0,
           "subject":"$_id.subject",
           "result":{$cond:[
                           {$eq:["$_id.importance","high"]},
                           {"high":"$count"},
                           {$cond:[{$eq:["$_id.importance","low"]},
                                   {"low":"$count"},
                                   {"medium":"$count"}]}]}}},
{$group:{"_id":"$subject",
         "low":{$sum:"$result.low"},
         "medium":{$sum:"$result.medium"},
         "high":{$sum:"$result.high"}}},
])
```

*test data:*

```
db.t.insert([
{"subject":"history","importance":"high"},
{"subject":"geography","importance":"low"},
{"subject":"history","importance":"low"},
{"subject":"history","importance":"medium"},
{"subject":"geography","importance":"low"},
{"subject":"history","importance":"low"}
])
```

*result:*

```
{ "_id" : "geography", "low" : 2, "medium" : 0, "high" : 0 }
{ "_id" : "history", "low" : 2, "medium" : 1, "high" : 1 }
```

Comment: If `importance` will contain about 20 fields how can I do that ? @batscream